# Как можно быстро проверить присутствие данной записи в БД?

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server

Допустим, есть некоторый список.

У этого списка есть `ID`, которые имеется в таблице `MS SQL`.

Как можно быстро сделать данную проверку?

Одиночные `SELECT` с целью проверки выполняются долго, если записей на проверку много...

Comment: Вариант 1 - проиндексировать поле с `ID`; Вариант 2 - считать все `ID` в память (в `HashSet`), и зарегистрировать тригеры на изменения

Comment: ID-это итак PK. Прогон 40 000 значений занимает минуты 2-3.

Comment: не знаю, что такое "прогон". Этого не может быть. Вы что, читаете всю таблицу?

Comment: В транзакции попытаться вставить этот ID. Если выпал эксепшен - значит запись уже есть в БД. Если вставилось - значит его не было; при это откатываем транзакцию.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov Ему нужно проверить 40 000 значений. Исключения - дорогой вариант.

Comment: Спустить как табличную переменную и сделать джойн на нее

Comment: Или,  как вариант,  вытащить все 40к записей на сторону c#, и там сравнить две коллекции. Это же небольшие объемы, меньше мегабайт данных. Можно вытаскивать с отсечением по between. Можно кэшировать, если проверку нужно повторять. Вообщем,  куча вариантов,  в зависимости от того,  что там за данные, и что о них известно.

Comment: @PashaPash Подозреваю, что записей больше. Это 40 000 значений надо проверить на существование в базе. Но одно ясно - 40 000 запросов делать не следует.

Comment: @Igor ну тут стоит взять и померять оба варианта. Sql server иногда очень лажает на выборке данных. Иногда из-за кривой статистики,  иногда он просто некоторые вещи не может учесть (например, ему нельзя донести, что данные в табличной переменной уже отсортированы). Вообщем,  там всегда есть простор для фантазии,  оптимизации и костылей :)

Comment: тут уж либо запрашивать пачками и сверять на клиенте, либо на сервер пачками залить во временную таблицу, и сравнить там

Answer (score 0):

А-a-a, я, наверное, догадался.

Используйте условие `IN`, вместо `=`, в `WHERE`. И задавайте по 200 значений. Это в 200 раз уменьшит количество запросов. Будет меньше секунды.

Comment: А IN ручками конструировать придется? Или что-то умное есть, где я могу задать один параметр IN и пульнуть список и он сам через запятую разложиться?

Comment: @iluxa1810 Вы сейчас не о том беспокоитесь. Вам надо сначала проверить, работает ли то, что я Вам пообещал :).